# Ruby : Trouble executing a sample program

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I downloaded a code sample written in Ruby.

I have the development environment ready on Windows Server 2008 using RailsInstaller and have Sublime Text 2 as my editor.

I tried some basic command line syntax and they seemed to work just fine, however I do not have any idea how to execute this sample which has two classes and no Main function method defined.

I am a C# developer and am unable to locate the entry point for the program. Whenever I build my code in Sublime, it returns the following error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'ruby', u'filepath']]
[dir:  folderpath]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\]
[Finished]
```

Can anybody help get me started?

Comment: It sounds like you need to get a Ruby book, or go through a tutorial to pick up the fundamentals of Ruby. While these are out of date, both are good starts: [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) and [Why's poignant guide to  Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing from http://rubyinstaller.org, the installer has an option to add the ruby executable to PATH. By default it is not checked. You can reinstall and check this option. Then Restarting ST2, you can build the code by CTRL+B.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the Ruby installation on your file path. I'm not sure that the Rails installer sets them up for you, but, judging from the path declaration above, it does not look like it is on your path.

To add the Ruby installation directory to your path on Windows, open a console and type:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<PathToRubydir>\bin
```